# Mean and variance of log-binomial distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, moments, lognormal-distribution

If X is a random variable with a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), then Y = exp(X) has a [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Likewise if X is a random variable with a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), then Y = exp(X) has a log-binomial distribution.

**My question**
In case of the log-normal distribution mean and variance are well known, for the log-binomial distribution I can't find any references.

Comment: **Hint**: $\mathbb E Y = m_X(1)$ where $m_X(t)$ is the moment-generating function of $X$. Now, what about the variance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use an entirely analogous technique to the one typically used to calculate the moments of a lognormal.

In particular, note that if $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y = e^X$, then $Y^k = e^{k X}$. But, $\E e^{kX} = m_X(k)$ where $m_X(t)$ is the moment-generating function of $X$ evaluated at $t$.

Hence,
$$
\E e^{k X} = m_X(k) = (1 - p + p e^k)^n \>,
$$
and so
$$
\E Y = m_X(1) = (1 + (e-1)p)^n
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Y) = m_X(2) - (m_X(1))^2 = (1+(e^2-1)p)^n - (1+(e-1)p)^{2n} \>.
$$

Other moments of $Y$ can be computed in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

See: 
Parameter Estimation and Goodness-of-Fit in Log Binomial Regression, 
L. Blizzard and D. W. Hosmer, 
Biometrical Journal
Volume 48, Issue 1, pages 5–22, February 2006

Comment: You should explain why this article helps solving the problem. Please provide some details.